# I can't load Identity User using EF core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm building a system where I have the `Order` entity in which each one has a `Sender`. I'm using

- ASP.Net core 2.2 (with Identity for managing the membership);
- EF core 2.2.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't add the user entity using `.Include(x => x.Sender)`. It is always returned as `null`.

This is the `Order` code:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public OrderStatusType CurrentOrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string PublicOrderId { get; set; }
    public Address PickupAddress { get; set; }
    public Address DropAddress { get; set; }

    public User Sender { get; set; }
    public User Receiver { get; set; }
    public User Creator { get; set; }

    public double ExpectedDistance { get; set; }
    public int ExpectedDuration { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `User` code:

```cs
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirastName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string LastNumber { get; set; }
    public string Gander { get; set; }
    public Language PrefairdLanguage { get; set; }
    public string Themapnail { get; set; }
    public Address DefaultAddress { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }
    public int Imei { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `DbContext` code:

```cs
public class MandoobContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
   // private readonly string connectionString;

    public MandoobContext(DbContextOptions<MandoobContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }


    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }    
}
```

This is the controller where I try to retrieve the data from the DB:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("Order/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Order(int id)
{
    Order order = _context.Orders
        .Include(x => x.DropAddress)
        .Include(x => x.PickupAddress)
        .Include(x => x.Sender)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    return View(order);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help if anyone has an idea.

Regards.

Comment: Not related to the question, but you should avoid using `FirstOrDefault` on your controller and use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` instead.

Comment: I could also get the user successfully.Could you share the data in your database?And what's the url that you send request?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `Sender` is set on the database on the given `Order`? I've created a working application with the VS .net template and added your model to it and it just works.

You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/tvdias/SO59114688.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24727399)

Comment: Thanks @Tân. There's no answer on the link, but a way for anyone to replicate the issue. Since I was able to get it working with the VS template + the code on the question there's no code to add to the answer. I believe it's a data issue...

Answer (score 0):

I get to resolve the problem by updating to .net Core 3.0 and Ef core3.0.
I don't know exactly what was going wrong but the update fixed it.

Regards

Comment: If you believe it is the best answer, you can accept it.